# ASP.NET MVC Relational DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two models

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }
    public string TeacherLname { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; } 
}
```

and I have a ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view where I'm  displaying  Departments

```
SchoolDbContext db = new SchoolDbContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    // retreive from database
    model.Departments = db.Departments.ToList();
    return View(model);
}
```

and on Details I want to display Teachers with a DepartmentID where I have a relation.

I'm trying to use this

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    model.Departments = db.Departments.ToList();
    model.Teachers = db.Teachers.Where(m => m.DepartmentID ==  m.DepartmentID);
    return View(model);
}
```

but there is a error

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<_167School.Models.Teacher>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<_167School.Models.Teacher>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\167School\167School\Controllers\DepartmentsController.cs   33

Comment: Why are you doing m => m.DepartmentId == m.DepartmentId? its the equivilent of context.Teachers.Where(m => true)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```html
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
  ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
  model.Departments = db.Departments.ToList();
  model.Teachers = db.Teachers.Where(m => m.DepartmentID ==  id).ToList();


  return View(model);
}
```

You you have to return the Teacher entity as a list since its defined as a List in your ViewModel class.

Comment: love the way you left m => m.DepartmentID ==  m.DepartmentID in

Comment: Nooo the delicious irony is ruined!! :(